# C++ How to set a callback to point to a non-static member function of an object instance?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-hydro, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu 13.10, Hydro Desktop-Full from source, C++]

I am having difficulty setting up callback functions for my ROS Topic subscribers, and would appreciate help.

Since all my Topics use the `std_msgs::String` type, I've defined the class shown below with a generic callback function and an instance variable which identifies the specific Topic.

```
class myCallback {

        const char * eventtype;

public:

        myCallback(const char * eventType) : eventtype(eventType) {}

        void generic_callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg) {
            std::cerr << this->eventtype << " heard: " << msg->data.c_str() << std::endl;
        }

};
```

For the ROS functionality in my project, I've created a separate class `gwrbclass.cpp` & `gwrbclass.h`, which include the `myCallback` class.  In the header file, I define `myCallback *callbackList[NUM_EVENT_TYPES]` as a private variable.  In the implementation, I instantiate the required myCallback objects for each entry in the callbackList and try to bind it to the node's subscriber object as shown below:

```
for (int j=0; j<NUM_EVENT_TYPES; j++) {
    callbackList[j] = new myCallback(eventName);
    subList[j] = (sNode[j])->subscribe(eventName, 1000, callbackList[j]->generic_callback);  << ERROR OCCURRING HERE
}
```

I'm getting an error stating : `reference to non-static member function must be called` , and as far as I can see, the method I'm calling is not static and therefore should work.
If I use `subList[j] = (sNode[j])->subscribe(...., &callbackList[j]->generic_callback);` the error becomes : `cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function`.

I'm confused as to why I'm getting this error (which I believe has something to do with std::bind, function typedef, wrapper functions, etc), and would appreciate some help as I can't figure out the syntax.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160386/c++-how-to-set-a-callback-to-point-to-a-non-static-member-function-of-an-object-instance?/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use the class member version of subscribe -- the doxygen for it is [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a317fe4c05919e0bf3fb5162ccb2f7c28).

Basically, it would be:

```
(sNode[j])->subscribe(eventName, 1000, &myCallback::generic_callback, callbackList[j]);
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
Thank you Fergs, exactly what was needed.  :)